# Render all 3d models in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a use case where in want to render all the 3d model formats. In my case I will get the 3d model file url from ajax call, so the difficulty I'm facing is I don't the which 3D Format file will come so how to render 3d format file irrespective of knowing the format of the file in three.js. Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: The three.js Editor [`Loader.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/Loader.js) may be helpful. The Editor supports drad-and-drop.

Comment: Thanks, @WestLangley will check this. Is there any ready example for it

Comment: https://threejs.org/editor